# Redirect without html <meta> or http Location (302) headers?

Tags: asp.net, http, redirect

I have little experience with lower level http, and I am curious about a situation which I've come across.

I was monitoring http traffic with **HttpWatch**, and noticed that an **IIS** asp.net server on submitting an .aspx login form returns a **200 OK** response, after which the browser redirects to a site inner (authenticated) page. The login response contains no redirection headers (no **302**), and the content of the response is plain text: "`22|pageRedirect||/Official/Default.aspx|`" (containing the relative redirection path).

If anyone could clear things up about how the redirection comes about, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Zypher's answer and Corey's comment, I did some investigating with Javascript Deobfuscator firefox plugin, and searched all the script loaded with the page for the "pageRedirect" string. The string was found in a piece of javascript from Telerik, as part of the functionality for some sort of script manager component, thus solving the mistery.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

They are probably sending the redirect from their web application

[like this](http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/redirect.asp)

[or this](http://www.stevenhargrove.com/redirect-web-pages/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Response.Redirect(URL) creates a "Location: URL" header, which isn't present in this case.

Comment: I think what zypher was asserting is that the application might be handling it all on the client side. i.e. This is some sort of AJAX-sh sort of application and the client side JavaScript knew to take that string, parse it and tell the browser to load that page w/o triggering a tradiional redirect.